# Discord bot returns ffmpeg error despite being added to PATH

Tags: ffmpeg, discord, youtube, bots

I am creating a Discord bot to play music via Youtube as practice with APIs. Every time I run the command to play a Youtube video I am met with "ffmpeg was not found". I have downloaded ffmpeg (as I'm on Windows) and moved the folder to my C: drive. Once done, I've added it to the path within environment variables. The error persists.

- I've added ffmpeg to my PATH as described in this [video](https://youtu.be/xyVY4n4_0MQ?t=125).
- Additionally, I've found forums where the suggested answer is to add ffmpeg to your PATH.

In command prompt, if I type "ffmpeg" it returns "'FFmpeg' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Here is my code:

````
from typing import Final
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from discord import Intents, Client, Message
from responses import get_response
import asyncio
import yt_dlp
import discord

#Step 0: Load our token from somewhere safe
load_dotenv()
#Final decorator makes it so that this cannot be overwritten or have subclasses
TOKEN: Final[str] = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')


voice_clients = {}
#Settings for the video download.
yt_dl_opts = {'format': 'bestaudio/best'}
ytdl = yt_dlp.YoutubeDL(yt_dl_opts)

#Settings for ffmpeg. 
ffmpeg_options = {'options': '-vn'}

# Step 1: Bot Setup - activate intents
intents: Intents = Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True #NOQA
client: Client = Client(intents=intents)

#Step 2: Message Functionality
async def send_message(message: Message, user_message: str):
    if not user_message:
        print('Message was empty because intents were not enabled... probably')
        return
    
    # The := "Walrus Operator" is used to prompt for input.
    if is_private := user_message[0] == '?':
        user_message = user_message[1:]
    
    try:
        response: str = get_response(user_message)
        await message.author.send(response) if is_private else await message.channel.send(response)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

#Step 3: Handling the startup for our bot.
        
@client.event
async def on_ready() -> None:
    print(f"{client.user} is now running")

#Step 4: Handle incoming messages
@client.event
async def on_message(message: Message) -> None:
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    
    username: str = str(message.author)
    user_message: str = message.content
    channel: str = str(message.channel)

    print(f"[{channel}] {username}: '{user_message}")
    await send_message(message, user_message)

    if message.content.startswith("!play"):
        try:
            url = message.content.split()[1]
            
            #Handles the voice connection that a bot has to a certain channel
            voice_client = await message.author.voice.channel.connect()
            voice_clients[voice_client.guild.id] = voice_client

            loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
            data = await loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: ytdl.extract_info(url, download=False))

            song = data['url']
            player = discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(song, **ffmpeg_options)

            voice_client.play(player)



        except Exception as err:
            print(err)

# Step 5: Main entry point
def main() -> None:
    client.run(token=TOKEN)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()```
````